# oracle db returns additional padding

Tags: oracle, padding

Could you advise why on one of our database below query:

```
select ' ' from dual
```

returns 32 blank characters:

```
'                                '
```

This happens ONLY on one environment, all other databases returns correctly only one space. I checked nls_parameters, they are the same. Any idea what could be reason for that? Some DB parameter? Some patch was not applied on that instance?

Other example:

```
select "!" || "!" from dual
```

produces:

```
"!!                                                              "
```

so it's !! + 62 spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check database parameter `cursor_sharing`. What is it set to? Set it to `EXACT`.

```
SQL> show parameters cursor_sharing

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------
cursor_sharing                       string      EXACT
SQL>
```

Comment: value was set to FORCE, when I changed it on session level, then it works fine. However, I can't reproduce this issue on other environments by setting this value to FORCE - is it possible to do this?

Comment: Check [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=whitespaces-bug) for explanation and reproducible example. Note also that changing `cursor_sharing` can have *side effects* on *other* statements...